# Wget a directory with exact filenames?

Tags: wget

The following works because I inserted the exact filename:

```
wget --referer=http://www.*****.com --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookie.txt http://www.*****.com/doc/GG-15252252.html
```

But if I just do it with the doc dir I will get a 403 error message:

```
Connecting to www.*****.com|***.**.***.**|:**... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2010-11-04 21:25:38 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

So I can't list the dir, what can I do?

Please help anybody and thanks :)!!

Comment: 403 means you aren't permitted to access the file[s]. So it probably isn't possible.

Comment: I am permitted. I got a user and password

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the username and password as part of the wget command using the `--http-user` and `--http-password` options.

However, I think it's more likely that the webserver is configured to not generate index pages automatically, or deny access to them.  This is a common way for webmasters to prevent people from getting a list of all files in a directory.

Comment: Hi ultrasawblade and thanks. I got this error when trying that: 

Connecting to www.*****.com|***.**.***.**|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 405 Method Not Allowed
2010-11-05 10:49:09 ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed.

Comment: The site is a asp.net auth with this form code:
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJOTY3MTE1MDA4ZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAgUaY3RsMDAkUkhlYWRlciRTZWFyY2hCdXR0b24FL2N0bDAwJHBoJGZzZWFyY2gkU2VhcmNoQ29yZUNvbnRyb2wkU2VhcmNoQnV0dG9uaIzURx8rrbEKPD6K4mM4D8rzvpc=" /></form>

Comment: Ahh.  Now this is making more sense.  The options I mentioned above only apply if the browser itself (not through javascript) pops up a dialog asking for username/password.  Anyway, 405 means the site wants a POST reply and not a GET, which is what you're sending it.  wget is able to send POST replies which are the common way for a browser to respond with filled out form data.  Read the wget man page to see how it works.